# How to format a partition under FreeBSD

Tags: filesystems, format, freebsd, hard-drive

I want to format a partition under FreeBSD and change it to UFS filesystem.
I searched the web but even the "fdisk" man page is not clear at all.
Any help would be clearly appreciated !

My current partition is :

```
fdisk /dev/da0
******* Working on device /dev/da0 *******
parameters extracted from in-core disklabel are:
cylinders=121601 heads=255 sectors/track=63 (16065 blks/cyl)

Figures below won't work with BIOS for partitions not in cyl 1
parameters to be used for BIOS calculations are:
cylinders=121601 heads=255 sectors/track=63 (16065 blks/cyl)

Media sector size is 512
Warning: BIOS sector numbering starts with sector 1
Information from DOS bootblock is:
The data for partition 1 is:
sysid 165 (0xa5),(FreeBSD/NetBSD/386BSD)
    start 63, size 1953520002 (953867 Meg), flag 80 (active)
    beg: cyl 0/ head 1/ sector 1;
    end: cyl 768/ head 254/ sector 63
The data for partition 2 is:
<UNUSED>
The data for partition 3 is:
<UNUSED>
The data for partition 4 is:
<UNUSED>
```

Comment: haven't used *BSD, but in linux land the `mkfs` collection of programs are used to create filesystems

Comment: yes I'm a Linux expert but it seems that FreeBSD is completely different when dealing with disks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My question was answered on :
https://forums.freebsd.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=19087&p=108748

Hope it will help someone else :-)

And as requested this is the answer from the link above (if it again becomes unavailable) :

*da0* is your drive. The first slice (partition) on that is called *s1*. fdisk says you have that slice created, so */dev/da0s1* should be present. That's what you format with *newfs*:

```
# newfs /dev/da0s1
# mount -t ufs /dev/da0s1 /mnt/usbdisk
# ls -ltr /mnt/usbdisk
total 2
drwxrwxr-x  2 root  operator  512 Nov  6 18:11 .snap
```

Best regards

Comment: nope, please add the essential parts of the link :D

Comment: yes seems the link has gone 404. The new link is : https://forums.freebsd.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=19087&p=108748

Answer (score 5):

`fdisk` for partitions
`bsdlabel` for slices (for the uninitiated, like partitions for partitions)
`newfs` for UFS (the native file system)

Quick 1 partition, 1 slice disk:

```
fdisk -BI [drive]
bsdlabel -wB [drive]s1
newfs [drive]s1a
```

After which you could mount it with something similar to:

```
mount [drive]s1a /mnt
```

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays you should use [gpart](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=gpart&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.1-RELEASE&format=html) to partition the disk (fdisk/disklabel are being overtaken by gpart since it supports [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table)), [newfs](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=newfs&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.1-RELEASE&format=html) to format UFS[2] partitions and [zpool](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=zpool&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.1-RELEASE&format=html) to create ZFS filesystems. For example to initialize a new, unused disk with a UFS filesystem:

GPT:
gpart create -s gpt adaX
gpart add -t freebsd-ufs adaX
newfs /dev/adaXp1

MBR:
gpart create -s mbr adaX
gpart add -t freebsd adaX
gpart create -s bsd adaXs1
gpart add -t freebsd-ufs adaXs1
newfs /dev/adaX1s1a

If the disk is already partitioned and you want to repartition it, see what's already present with:

gpart show adaX

You can then delete partitions using "gpart delete -i y adaX:

gpart delete -i 4 adaX

You can use "gpart destroy" to destroy the scheme if you want to change it from MBR to GPT for example:

gpart destroy adaX
gpart create -s gpt adaX

[GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) is generally preferred nowadays unless you have to interoperate with systems which don't understand it since it can break the 2TB limit and have up to 2^32-1 partitions (in theory!).